# How can I include doxygen perlmod in my perlscript?

Tags: perl, doxygen

How can I include doxygen perlmod in my perlscript?

I've noticed that you can generate a alternative output with doxygen that is called perlmod, 
but I can't find any examples on how to use this part.

I've found 2 nice files in there DoxyDocs.pm and DoxyStructure.pm, 
and they contain some kind of nice structure that represents the source code 
(and it looks like a some array/hashcode).

But since my "advanced perl" is a little bit rusty, I'm having problems getting started with this little idea ...

Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks
Johan

---

Should I use the -I to perl and "use" those .pm?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Icode/doc/perlmod/

use strict;
use warnings;

use DoxyStructure;
use DoxyDocs;
```

Or should I include those file in another way? maybe something like this? but the problem is that I can't enable strict and warning since I the get errors backs...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

#use strict;
#use warnings;

require "code/doc/perlmod/DoxyDocs.pm";
```

---

*Update*

In order to enable perlmod in Doxygen I switched it on with these flags in the Doxyfile:

```
# If the GENERATE_PERLMOD tag is set to YES Doxygen will
# generate a Perl module file that captures the structure of
# the code including all documentation. Note that this
# feature is still experimental and incomplete at the
# moment.

GENERATE_PERLMOD       = YES

# If the PERLMOD_LATEX tag is set to YES Doxygen will generate
# the necessary Makefile rules, Perl scripts and LaTeX code to be able
# to generate PDF and DVI output from the Perl module output.

PERLMOD_LATEX          = YES
```

Then doxygen create a new dir called perlmod in the same directory as the html and latex one, and in perlmod we find the lists I try to use.

- **perlmod/DoxyDocs.pm**
- perlmod/doxyformat.tex
- perlmod/doxylatex.pl
- perlmod/doxylatex-structure.pl
- perlmod/doxylatex.tex
- perlmod/doxyrules.make
- **perlmod/DoxyStructure.pm**
- perlmod/Makefile

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [*perlpod*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html)? That's more of a Perl standard than Doxygen. It can produce plain text, HTML, or nroff formatted output (with the `pod2text`, `pod2html`, and `pod2man` tools). Why don't you use that instead?